# Sending attachment with reqwest

Tags: http, asynchronous, post, rust, reqwest

I'm trying to do a POST request using `reqwest`. I need to send attachments in my request. I am looking for the equivalent of

```
curl -F attachment=@file.txt
```

In older versions (see [here](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.3/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html)) it was as simple as

```rust
let file = fs::File::open("much_beauty.png")?;
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let res = client.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
    .headers(construct_headers())
    .body(file)
    .send()?;
```

But for newer versions (see [here](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html)) looks like the functionality has been removed. I get the error:

```
21 |         .body(file)
   |          ^^^^ the trait `From<File>` is not implemented for `Body`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Body as From<&'static [u8]>>
             <Body as From<&'static str>>
             <Body as From<Response>>
             <Body as From<String>>
           and 2 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Body>` for `File`
```

Despite the [official documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/) claiming

> The basic one is by using the `body()` method of a `RequestBuilder`. This lets you set the exact raw bytes of what the body should be. It accepts various types, including `String`, `Vec<u8>`, and `File`.

Comment: I have recently [filed an issue](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/1149) regarding the this part of documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new API may not implement `From<File>` for `Body` anymore but does implement `From<Vec<u8>>` for `Body` and we can easily convert a `File` into a `Vec<u8>`.

In fact, there's already a handy function in the standard library called `std::fs::read` which will read an entire file and store it in a `Vec<u8>`. Here's the updated working example:

```rust
let byte_buf: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read("much_beauty.png")?;
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let res = client.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
    .headers(construct_headers())
    .body(byte_buf)
    .send()?;
```